# Django models missing. Why my django models disappeared on production server, if on development server runs fine?

Tags: django, apache, wsgi

im running django development server and all models works fine..
But when i have configured and run apache through wsgi, only "Groups" and "Users" could be administrated, my own models disappears:

[screenshot of admin pages from development server and production server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw0qy.png)

Why, please?

(After first comments here is my edit:)

I want to use django on localhost only, to fill and administrate small database file. Project is not intended for web hosting yet. I have no html views and templates defined. So I have try some simple view for testing purposes only, and problem is the same. Web server cant find some includes..:

[image2: simple view also dosen't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrKBF.png)

Comment: Are you using the same file settings file for dev vs. prod? Are your models properly registered in the admin? Can you reach your model in the non-admin?

Comment: Also, have you run `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py` migrate on your production server? If your settings use different database connections, then you'll need to sync your prod DB with your models.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your production settings file has all the apps included. Normally when you don't see your admin models its due to the app missing from the list of apps included in settings.py.

Comment: yes, in setting.py notes are included: INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'notes',
)

Comment: When you are in the django shell (or better yet, shell_plus), can you load the models?

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem. Had to restart uwsgi
`sudo service uwsgi restart`

Maybe for you it's wsgi or apache. Something in the pipeline needs to know you changed some python code.